# Visual Studio C# - How do I turn off autocomplete (not intellisense)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

So I didn't use to have this issue as much in older versions, and it even then it was easy to get used to, but i got VS 2019 recently and now when I write code it'll randomly autocomplete half way in and add shit I didn't write WHILE IM STILL WRITING. I don't press enter, I don't click on anything, it'll just add what it thinks I want without any confirmation.

I tried searching how to disable this, but I only ever find how to turn off intellisense recommendations altogether (Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense). I don't want to disable the completion list from showing up, I WANT intellisense, I just want it to let me code without inserting new code on it's own. Just show me recommendations, don't automatically add them in for me without any input from me.

Comment: You are probably accidentally clicking Tab.

Comment: Have you tried to [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)? Text Editor will not autocomplete half way, if you didn’t click on anything to trigger it. Also if you installed any related extensions, please make sure that they will not affect Text Editor.

Comment: its a fresh install of VS 2019 from a fresh install of unity. :/

Comment: i realized the trigger that seems to do it is opening a bracket "(" . It's very annoying when I'm writing a new method and it autocompletes to some method override or something. How do I turn this off?? I dont see intellicode anywhere.

Comment: Could you please share us some codes/examples and describe which key you have pressed and then what happens? I'd like to test and try to reproduce on my side and find the issue. Besides, not sure if Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > General > `Automatic brace completion` option meets your requirement.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Space shortcut - Switch between automatic and tab-only Intellisense completion. Menu: Edit > Intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

```
Edit -> Intellisense -> Switch Between Automatic and Tab-Only IntelliSense Completion
```

Had the same problem, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to disable the IntelliCode. you can do it by

> Choose Extensions > Manage Extensions, find and select the IntelliCode
> extension, and then click Disable

Comment: In Manage Extensions, under Installed, I search for intellicode and nothing shows up. (Tried searching inte too, still nothing)

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue with Visual Studio Community using C# and Resharper on a fresh installation.

This seems to occur on writing invalid syntax, Visual Studio replaces whatever is written with it's closest valid guess when the user presses space.  Specifically I was typing in a variable without declaring a type first.

```
output // gets overwritten automatically with XmlOutputMethod
var output // does not get overwritten automatically
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to disable this feature in Visual Studio.  Hopefully this information is of some use.

I've recorded a short video of my text being overwritten by Visual Studio, which can be found [here](https://github.com/justinbourb/myscripts/blob/master/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%202021-10-11%2009-50-20_Trim.mp4)